# puppet unkown function validate

Tags: linux, debian, puppet

I have imported this module requiretty for sudoers for puppet from [requiretty](https://code.google.com/p/lutak/source/browse/sudoers/lib/puppet/parser/functions/validate.rb?r=d28eb3412dc27073b2cd15a43d1224e3e18bc294)

i have done a test on validate function and it does not give any error when doing an irb check.

```
[root@yeovil functions]# irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'puppet'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require  '/var/lib/puppet/parser/functions/validate.rb'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Puppet::Parser::Functions.function(:validate)
=> "function_validate"
irb(main):004:0> "function_validate"
=> "function_validate"
irb(main):005:0> 
[2]+  Stopped    

         irb
```

however when I run " puppet agent -t " it returns

```
"Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Unknown function validate "
```

UPDATE:

fixed it by creating

```
{modulepath}/{module}/lib/puppet/parser/functions
```

but now get this error

```
SERVER: Can't synthesize edge: Sudo::Requiretty[kshk] -notifies- requiretty is being called (param notify)
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed: had a notify entry in the module definition, after removing it worked cool